# How to unload previous level (class) in iOS

Tags: ios, game-development

In my game, when I load a new level, the previous level seems to be still remaining in the view.. Each level has its own class and they all draw something on the screen. So if I have 2 or more levels of images loaded, that makes my game too slow. What can I do to unload the previous level? Thanks in advance..

```
- (void) finishedLevel: (Level *) level
{

        levelNumber++;
    levelClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Level_%d", levelNumber]);
    if (!levelClass) levelClass = [Level class];

    currentLevel = [[levelClass alloc] initWithView: self.mainView];

    self.mainView.levelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %d", levelNumber];

    gameRunning = NO;
}
```

I tried using the following but didn't really work

```
levelClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level_%d", levelNumber-1]);

    [levelClass removeFromSuperview];
```

Error message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Level_1 removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107644'
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you should release `currentLevel` before allocating the new one. Also, what assets are involved in each level? Do you have sprites, models, sounds, etc.? If so, you'll want to free those, as well.

Comment: No I am not using arc.. i tried releasing currentLevel before increasing the level number but my app crashed.. it's a maze game so each level at the moment has hole, wall coordinates and image names..

Comment: Well, the only way to not have your old levels take up memory is to release them. You should explore why it crashes when you release it.